# Python: Handling different HTTP status codes using the requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the `requests` library to make requests to an API. However, I am not sure how to handle different status codes. I am particularly interested in handling status code 500, as that is part of my task.

1: Is a try/except block like I have an acceptable way of handling error codes?

2: How should I handle 500 status code? Would retrying 5 times once per second, then exiting be acceptable? If so, I don't know how to implement that without wrapping the whole function in a `for` loop (which seems bad practice).

Here is my function that makes HTTP requests:

```
def make_request(type, endpoint, h, data=None):
    try:
        url = f'https://example.net/not-important/{endpoint}'
        if type == 'GET':
            r = requests.get(url, headers=h)
        elif type == 'POST':
            r = requests.post(url, headers=h, json=data)
        # r = requests.get('https://httpstat.us/500')
        r.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        if e.response.status_code == 500:
            # 500 logic here. retry?
        else:
            print(f'An error occurred: {e}\n{e.response.status_code}')
            sys.exit(1)

    else:
        return r.json()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you implement [exponential back-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff). For example, first try after x seconds and then twice as long as the last wait time. This is the common practice for retries. Recursion often looks cleaner than a loop. You could give your `make_request` function an additional parameter with a default value of 0 that counts retries. As always with recursion make sure to have a break point e.g. 5 retries to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: _Recursion often looks cleaner than a loop_ seems dubious and subjective. For this instance I really don't think it's the right tool.

Comment: @Reinderien I agree, but OP did not want a loop, so I offered an alternative.

Comment: OP suspected that wrapping in a loop is bad practice, but I disagree. Some modicum of reassurance may help them see a different perspective.

Comment: @Reinderien Especially for handling different errors with different strategies, and only some of them by retries, recursion is often cleaner. Also a loop around a `try` block that continues only if an exception is thrown is a bit weird, and usually requires `break` or early `return` in the good case, or an extra state variable. Recursion is much more straightforward and requires less lines of code and less levels of indentation.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should reduce to one call to [request](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request). You don't need to separate by method; just pass `type` to the `method` argument.

Don't call a variable `type`; that's a built-in.

Don't call an argument `h`; just call it `headers`.

Add PEP484 type hints to your signature, something like

```
def make_request(
    method: Literal['GET', 'POST'],
    endpoint: str,
    headers: dict[str, str],
    data: Optional[dict[str, Any]] = None,
) -> dict[str, Any]:
```

Don't `exit()` from a utility function. If you want to propagate a (possibly fatal) error, just `raise` or perhaps `raise MyException('An error occurred' ...) from e`.

Answer (score 2):

> 1: Is a try/except block like I have an acceptable way of handling error codes?

By default, `requests` library does not raise exceptions based on HTTP status codes. Instead, status code is returned in [`status_code`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) attribute of response object:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Exceptions, though, can be raised using [`raise_for_status`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) method, as you did.

However, in my opinion, it makes little sense to raise exception only to catch it int the very next line. So I'd get rid of try/except and `raise_for_status` and just inspect `status_code`:

```
def make_request(type, endpoint, h, data=None):
    url = f'https://example.net/not-important/{endpoint}'
    r = requests.request(type, url, headers=h, json=data)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json() # ok
    elif r.status_code == 500:
        pass  # not ok, handle 500
    else:
        pass  # not ok, handle other codes
```